# Facebook Style 'Read More' instead of standard Pager in QuickTabs?

Tags: ajax

I am using Quicktabs to display a few views (grid style). At the bottom I am using the standard Pager that comes with QuickTabs. Is it possible to replace that with a 'Show More' link (ajax style?) Example would be at the bottom of a Facebook Wall, or here- http://gdgt.com/answers/

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Views Infinite Scroll](http://drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll).

> Views Infinite Scroll provides a pluggable pager that enables Views infinite scrolling by using jquery.autopager plugin. Using this module with Views page display will load another page whenever the user reaches the bottom of the page.

Comment: exactly what I'm looking for!  It's giving me some errors- so I sent an email to the developer.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I would say [Views Load More](http://drupal.org/project/views_load_more) but there's a more thorough answer over at [Load more content with ajax when clicking more link in a view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4920/load-more-content-with-ajax-when-clicking-more-link-in-a-view) with a comparison of all the views plugin that implement this feature.